# buttons can't be pressed with flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with the buttons I can't click on them...
I just create a class answer that takes two parameters from the main

[this how the buttons looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgvk4.png)

**this is the answer class that took two parameters**

```
 class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answerText;
  final Function x;

  const Answer(this.x, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: x(),
        child: Text(
          answerText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }`
```

**and this is the main class**
i just call the Answer class and i add to it the function answerquestion and  string answer

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _i = 0;
  void answerquestion() {
    print("good ");
    print(_i);
  }

  var question = [
    "what's ur fav color?",
    "what's ur fav animal?",
    "what's ur fav food?"
  ];
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Quiz App"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween(1),
            children: <Widget>[
              Question(question[1]),
              Answer(answerquestion, "ans1"),
              Answer(answerquestion, 'ans2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to these stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please add code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are executing the function on the widget creation. The correct sintax should be either

```dart
onPressed: () => x(),
```

or:

```dart
onPressed: x
```